# How to use Google Apps Script as a submission form

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script

I'm relatively new to Google Apps Script. I'm trying to build a script, as well as Html, to create a site where I have people submit their names, age  and so on (basic info for a test site). After they do so I want it the information to be automatically recorded into a google sheets file. Issue I'm having is that I don't know how to record the submissions using Google Apps Script to the google sheets file. I also want an email sent to me automatically after someone submits something. I tried looked at the API Ref but don't really have a solid starting point. I'm learning Javascript now but would like an idea of how Google Apps Script would work if I tried making a program like this. Thank you

Comment: Please do not vandalise your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large ([under the CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Forms (https://www.google.com/forms/about/) will do most of this for you without any code.  Once you have a basic form working, you can enhance that form with Google Apps Script if needed.

Comment: The thing is, I want to do it via code. I know forms is more convenient, but I want to learn to do it by means of code for future's sake.

Comment: Think of it as me wanting know how Google forms records informations, does automatic email and processes all of the input info to google sheets.

Comment: I recommend that you start with some of the Google Apps Script tutorials.  Once you have some sample code attempts, re-post your question with the sample code you have written.  Perhaps you could start here to learn how to build a web service that talks to Google Apps Script: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

Comment: Here is the sample code that I have. The error that I keep getting for this is "parameters not defined"

Comment: I will add it to the question @terrywb